Correct way of merging two CSV files without duplicates based on a column in Python
I want to merget 2 CSV files into one CSV and remove all duplicated rows based on a column (second column).
Here is my first CSV file:
    Skufnoo,748702985,-6026769894509215039,Ð’ÑƒÐ¿ÑÐµÐ½ÑŒ Ð¿ÑƒÐ¿ÑÐµÐ½ÑŒ â¤ï¸â€ðŸ©¹ðŸ’—,AA2888 áž…áž¶áž€áŸ‹áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž“áž·áž„áž€áž¶ážŸáž»áž¸ážŽáž¼áž¢áž“áž¡áž¶áž‰ (070645555),1746008070,False,False,4,True,False,0
    mAtkmb,5213786988,4161254730445748607,Ð”Ð°Ð½Ð¸ÑÐ»ÑŒ Ð‘Ð»Ð¸Ð½Ð¾Ð²,AA2888 áž…áž¶áž€áŸ‹áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž“áž·áž„áž€áž¶ážŸáž»áž¸ážŽáž¼áž¢áž“áž¡áž¶áž‰ (070645555),1746008070,False,False,False,False,False,0
    sheluvjoseph,1421438213,8544915453690665435,áž¢áž“ ážŸáŸ†áž¢áž»áž›,AA2888 áž…áž¶áž€áŸ‹áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž“áž·áž„áž€áž¶ážŸáž»áž¸ážŽáž¼áž¢áž“áž¡áž¶áž‰ (070645555),1746008070,False,False,5,True,False,0

Second CSV file:
    cchamnap,748702985,-7259273529368744780,Chim,AA2888 áž…áž¶áž€áŸ‹áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž“áž·áž„áž€áž¶ážŸáž»áž¸ážŽáž¼áž¢áž“áž¡áž¶áž‰ (070645555),1746008070,False,False,5,True,False,0
    chhounkha,765670208,3636141294788837002,Chhuon Sokha,AA2888 áž…áž¶áž€áŸ‹áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž“áž·áž„áž€áž¶ážŸáž»áž¸ážŽáž¼áž¢áž“áž¡áž¶áž‰ (070645555),1746008070,False,False,False,False,False,0
    CHHORMNIMOL8,5213786988,5104468652588260401,ážŒáž¸ ážŽáž¶.,AA2888 áž…áž¶áž€áŸ‹áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž“áž·áž„áž€áž¶ážŸáž»áž¸ážŽáž¼áž¢áž“áž¡áž¶áž‰ (070645555),1746008070,False,False,5,True,False,0
    Chhailin17,1133044248,6931066845789435875,Chhai Lin,AA2888 áž…áž¶áž€áŸ‹áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž“áž·áž„áž€áž¶ážŸáž»áž¸ážŽáž¼áž¢áž“áž¡áž¶áž‰ (070645555),1746008070,False,False,5,True,False,0

Output file (own_updated2.csv) should be:
    Skufnoo,748702985,-6026769894509215039,Ð’ÑƒÐ¿ÑÐµÐ½ÑŒ Ð¿ÑƒÐ¿ÑÐµÐ½ÑŒ â¤ï¸â€ðŸ©¹ðŸ’—,AA2888 áž…áž¶áž€áŸ‹áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž“áž·áž„áž€áž¶ážŸáž»áž¸ážŽáž¼áž¢áž“áž¡áž¶áž‰ (070645555),1746008070,False,False,4,True,False,0
    mAtkmb,5213786988,4161254730445748607,Ð”Ð°Ð½Ð¸ÑÐ»ÑŒ Ð‘Ð»Ð¸Ð½Ð¾Ð²,AA2888 áž…áž¶áž€áŸ‹áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž“áž·áž„áž€áž¶ážŸáž»áž¸ážŽáž¼áž¢áž“áž¡áž¶áž‰ (070645555),1746008070,False,False,False,False,False,0
    sheluvjoseph,1421438213,8544915453690665435,áž¢áž“ ážŸáŸ†áž¢áž»áž›,AA2888 áž…áž¶áž€áŸ‹áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž“áž·áž„áž€áž¶ážŸáž»áž¸ážŽáž¼áž¢áž“áž¡áž¶áž‰ (070645555),1746008070,False,False,5,True,False,0
    chhounkha,765670208,3636141294788837002,Chhuon Sokha,AA2888 áž…áž¶áž€áŸ‹áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž“áž·áž„áž€áž¶ážŸáž»áž¸ážŽáž¼áž¢áž“áž¡áž¶áž‰ (070645555),1746008070,False,False,False,False,False,0
    Chhailin17,1133044248,6931066845789435875,Chhai Lin,AA2888 áž…áž¶áž€áŸ‹áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž“áž·áž„áž€áž¶ážŸáž»áž¸ážŽáž¼áž¢áž“áž¡áž¶áž‰ (070645555),1746008070,False,False,5,True,False,0

I have tried the following codes:
    import pandas as pd
    import csv


    df1 = pd.read_csv("own1.csv")
    df2 = pd.read_csv("own2.csv")
    merged = pd.concat([df1,df2])

    with open('own_updated.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding='utf-8') as nf:
        merged.to_csv(nf, index=False)

    with open('own_updated.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8") as in_file, open('own_updated2.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding="utf8") as out_file:
        in_data = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=',')
        writer=csv.writer(out_file)
        tracks = set()          # Tracking duplicates of the second column's cell

        for row in in_data:
            key = row[1]
            if key not in tracks:
                writer.writerow(row)
                tracks.add(key)

It works well. But the problem is there is an extra file which is not needed own_updated.csv. How can I store all data from merging two CSV files without creating a file which is own_updated.csv, i.e. store them in a memory, then process the removal of duplicates based on the second column?

Your question is how you can do the same thing you are already doing, but without writing the results to another file, is that correct?

yes. I want to store all merged data in a memory instead of writing to own_updated.csv, then process that merged data for removal of duplicates based on a column as mentioned

I think you could use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672524/how-to-create-in-memory-file-object, but probably there is a better way to do this with pandas directly.

If you look at the answers in your earlier question you should be able to see how you could populate an in-memory dictionary

You should use the build in pandas method drop_duplicates. Here is the code:
import pandas as pd
import csv

df1 = pd.read_csv("own1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("own2.csv")
merged = pd.concat([df1, df2])

# As from example '1' and '2' are the indices of the columns based on which you want to remove duplicates
column_names = merged.columns[[1, 2]]

df_no_duplicates = merged.drop_duplicates(subset=column_names)

with open('own_updated.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding='utf-8') as nf:
    df_no_duplicates.to_csv(nf, index=False)


Thanks. Your codes work well. If I am based on one column, this should be: column_names = merged.columns[1]?

This doesn't work if the first line is different.

This is the best solution as the codes are flexible for one, two or multiple columns for removal of duplicates. Many thanks for great community.

That gives me weird output. Lines from file 2 are concatenated with file 1: Skufnoo,748702985,-6026769894509215039,...,cchamnap,-7259273529368744780, anybody else, @JamesBlack?

You don't need to to use an additional file, just drop the duplicates from the merged dataframe
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('own1.csv', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('own2.csv', header=None)
merged = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates([1], keep='first').reset_index(drop=True)

with open('own_updated.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as nf:
    merged.to_csv(nf, index=False, header=False)


Wow very simple with panda, but there are errors. Thanks

@JamesBlack what errors?

C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\Telegram auto adder\Tools\data cleaners\merge2csv.py:7: DtypeWarning: Columns (1,2,5,6,7,9,11) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
df1 = pd.read_csv('own1.csv', header=None)

@JamesBlack it weird, it's the same code to read the files as yours. Try maybe df1 = pd.read_csv('own1.csv', header=None, dtype='unicode')?

yes, no more errors, and your codes work really well too. Not sure who should I give tick to?

Keep it simple...:
import csv

results = dict()

files = ["own1.csv", "own2.csv"]

for file in files:
    with open(file, newline="") as fd:
        for row in csv.reader(fd):
            results[row[1]] = row

At this point the results dictionary has the merged data in its values(). The dictionary keys based on row[1] cannot, by definition, have duplicates

That doesn't give the result OP asked for: in your solution the last key evaluated/stored wins, but OP is asking for the first key to win. You'll need to do something like check if the key doesn't already exist in results before adding it and the row.

@ZachYoung All he asks is that duplicates are removed. Sure, the output he shows retains the first of any duplicates but that's not stated as a specific requirement
